# PathMustExists and FileMustExists in SWT FileDialog

Tags: java, swt, filedialog

To date I only used Swing to build graphical user interfaces but now I also want to make myself familiar with the Standard Widget Toolkit.
I already read the documentation and built a simple app.
My problem is now to use the FileDialog component.

I did the following code:

```
FileDialog openFileDialog = new FileDialog(shell, SWT.OPEN);
openFileDialog.setFilterExtensions(new String[] { "*.txt" });
openFileDialog.setFilterNames(new String[] { "Text files (*.txt)" });
openFileDialog.setText("Open file");
openFileDialog.open();
```

But I found no methods to set flags like "PathMustExists" or "FileMustExists".
Is this not possible with FileDialog?
Do I have to extend the class to implement that functionality? If so, how I have to proceed?
Or this there a better OpenFileDialog component (maybe in JFace) from which I don't know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no options for this.

Since you are specifying `SWT.OPEN` you will get a file dialog specialized for opening existing files. Depending on which platform you are running on this dialog may not allow non-existent files to be selected at all (certainly true on Mac OS X). Still you should check the file after the dialog returns.